# How does ActiveRecord manage the conversion of model values to the appropriate database format for a given column?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

**Context:** I am creating a method that can construct mass insert statements from json objects (generated from ActiveRecord models ex: Post.new.to_json) using Arel's InsertManager and the to_sql method to generate individual insert statements, then parsing the individual queries into a mass insert query.

**Problem:** I am getting data format errors from the database because the created_at field has the wrong formatting. The to_json method saves datetime fields with the following format 
"2014-11-14T09:39:17.422-07:00" whereas the database wants it in this format "2014-11-14 09:39:17".  I realized that *I could get this problem with other fields* as well, where the data is correct, but it is just not formatted correctly.

**Question:** **How can I handle that data correctly without writing all my own rules?**

I'm assuming ActiveRecord has a library that can do this because the sql is correct even though the value stored is not the same as in the query:

```
p = Post.new
p.created_at = Time.now.to_s(:db) # => "2014-11-14 19:20:55"
p.created_at                      # => Fri, 14 Nov 2014 19:20:55 MST -07:00
p.created.to_json                 # => "\"2014-11-14T19:20:55.000-07:00\""

p.save
# =>INSERT INTO `posts` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-11-15 02:20:55', '2014-11-14 19:25:07')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while scouring the internet for answers I stumbled upon [some methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting.html) used by ActiveRecord connections.  It appears that the correct way to cast the data into the proper format is with:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.type_cast Time.now, Post.column_types["created_at"] 
# => "2014-12-01 15:53:05"
```

and if you want the value quoted (and it does a little data conversion at least) then use:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote Time.now 
# => "'2014-12-01 15:54:40'"
```

Comment: So while this solution helps, it is not ideal.  It does return database friendly formats, but adds extra quotation marks, which my database doesn't like (in date fields, or fields where the character limit is 1, etc)